# Price history extraction from steam market

Tags: python, python-requests, steam

I am using following URL to extract the JSON file for the price history 
[https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=P90%20|%20Blind%20Spot%20(Field-Tested)](https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=P90%20%7C%20Blind%20Spot%20(Field-Tested))

The python code I am using:

```
    item = requests.get(URL, cookies={'steamLogin': steamid}); # get item data
    print(str(currRun),' out of ',str(len(allItemNames))+' code: '+str(item.status_code))
    item = item.content
    item = json.loads(item)
```

Now I went to almost all the solutions that was posted in this community but I am still getting status code as 400 and Items as [].

When I copy paste the URL and open it in browser I am able to see the JSON file with required data but somehow the Jupyter notebook is unable to detect the content

I also tried Beautiful soup to read the content with the following code:

```
     r = requests.get(url)
     #below code extracts the whole HTML Code of above URL 
     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
     table = soup.find_all('pre')
     print(table)
```

Output: []

Comment: What exactly is your question about these observations?

Comment: When I open link I also see `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are getting `[]` because you are not authorized, so you recieve empty json array. You can check it by opening link in incognito (`Ctrl+Shift+N`) mode.

To authorize you need to set `Cookie` header to your request, so your code will be as this:

```
import requests

url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?appid=730&market_hash_name=P90%20%7C%20Blind%20Spot%20(Field-Tested)"

headers = {
    "Cookie": "Your cookie"
}

json = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
...
```

**How to find Cookie (Chrome)**

0. Go to link with json
1. Press F12 to open Chrome Development Toolkit.
2. Open `Network` tab
3. Reload page.
4. Double click on first sent request
5. Open `Headers` subtab
6. Scroll to `Request Headers`
7. Find `Cookie` header

Comment: Do not share this cookie, or store it in public places. Although Steam must have cookie stealing protection (binding session id to ip for example), it is still better to not share your cookies anywhere.